# Loop com um pool.query pg(postgres) no node, está dando conflito na entrega dos responses

Tags: node.js, postgresql, loop, pooling

Sou iniciante em programação com node,
Espero que alguém possa me ajudar,
 O problema é o seguinte, estou fazendo um app com node em que tem um loop for com o body da requisição(req.body) e a cada iteração faço uma consulta no banco de dados postgres com o pool.query da biblioteca pg, depois eu coloco tudo em um array e envio no response(res).
 Só que quando testo no navegador para uma requisição ele funciona normalmente, mas quando abro duas abas e faço duas requisições simultaneamente, ele mistura os dados dos responses e fica os dados no response  errado.
Não sei onde está o erro, segue uma parte do código:

```
async enviaResposta(req, res){

const objResultadoFinal = [];
const body = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));



//extrai os dados e faz a consulta no banco
 async function ExtraiEformataDados(){


    for(prop in body){

        const conteudo = body[prop];
        let select = "";

        //codigo que manipula o select 
        manipula a variável select
        //fim do do código que manipula o select


        if(select != ""){

            await pool.query(select)
            .then(res => {
                 objResultadoFinal.push({ id:prop, msgRecebidanoServidor:conteudo, resultado:res.rows});

             })
            .catch(err => {

                objResultadoFinal.push({ id: prop, msgRecebidanoServidor:conteudo, resultado:[err.stack]});



        }); 
        }else{
            objResultadoFinal.push({ id: prop, msgRecebidanoServidor:conteudo, resultado:[]}); 
        }


    }   

}

async function enviaDados(){

    await ExtraiEformataDados();

    return await res.status(200).json({
    message: "dados enviados com sucesso",
    data: objResultadoFinal
});
}

 enviaDados();
```

}

Comment: Reginaldo, como você gerencia as sessões de seu servidor? Você está sabendo que em NodeJS, diferentemente do PHP e do ASP, você tem escrever o seu próprio session manager? Se não souber do que estou falando: [`express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session).

Comment: @Augusto Vasques, obrigado pela dica eu não tinha muita noção de sessões, dei uma lida no link, mas descobri onde estava o problema, era simples: no loop for in eu coloquei (prop in body), mas na verdade era (let prop in body), isso me causou o problemão que passei dias tentado achar o erro.Mas pelo menos aprendi um assunto novo com sua ajuda. Fica com Deus!!!